# How to limit a counter to a specific number?

Tags: jquery, counter

I've set up a counter to track how many times a next and previous button is clicked.

1. click = one 
   Previous Button Appears
2. click = nine
   Next Button Disappears

I want to limit the amount the counter can be. For Example 10. Once it reaches 10.

```
// Buttons
var count = 0;
$("#mod3-6-1_nextbutton").click(function() {
    $("#actions-container").css({
        "top" : "-=110px"
    });

    count += 1;
    counter();
});
$("#mod3-6-1_backbutton").click(function() {
    $("#actions-container").css({
        "top" : "+=110px"
    });
    count -= 1;
    counter();
});

function counter() {

    if (count == 0) {
        $("#mod3-6-1_backbutton").css({
            "top" : "-9999px",
            "left" : "-9999px",
        }); 
    }
    if (count == 1) {
        $("#mod3-6-1_backbutton").css({
            "top" : "20px",
            "left" : "44px",    
        }); 
    }
    if (count > 9) {
        $("#mod3-6-1_nextbutton").css({
            "top" : "-9999px",
            "left" : "-9999px",
        });
        $("#actions-container").css({
                 "top" : "-990px"
             });
    }
    else {
            $("#mod3-6-1_nextbutton").css({
                   "top" : "20px",
                  "left" : "700px",

        }); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get the work done for you

```
return (counter < 10);
```

This will set the return value to false once the counter is 10 and your code will not get executed.. Once returned false;

```
   var count = 0;
$("#mod3-6-1_nextbutton").click(function() {
    count += 1;
    if (count > 9) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (count == 9) {
        // DO nothing
    }
    else {
        $("#actions-container").css({
            "top": "-=110px"
        });
    }
    counter();
});
$("#mod3-6-1_backbutton").click(function() {

    count -= 1;
    if (count > 9) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (count == 0) {
        // DO nothing
    }
    else {
        $("#actions-container").css({
            "top": "+=110px"
        });
    }
    counter();
});​
```

Comment: That seems to work, although I would really like to stop the position change after the counter reaches 9 or 0

Comment: Then write up the .css in the ifelse loop itself

Answer (score 0):

Only do actions if count is less then your max, and since the next buttons disappears the count should not be able to go above your max anyway. A sloppy way of doing it is just to say

```
if (count < max) {
    // make sure the right button shows and
    // do stuff
} else {
    // make button disappear
}
```

you can also replace those css lines with css class and using addClass()/removeClass() to implement the styles. to make it more robust, you can get the max count from the number of slides you have

```
var max = $('#slider .slides').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of duplicated code, just an example of what you have to do.

```
var count = 0;
var LIMIT = 10;

$("#mod3-6-1_nextbutton, #mod3-6-1_backbutton").click(function() {
    var top, count;
    if($(this).is('#mod3-6-1_nextbutton')) {
        if(count == LIMIT) return false;
        top = "-=110px";
        val = 1;
    } else {
        top = "+=110px";
        val = -1;
    }

    $("#actions-container").css({
        "top" : top
    });
    count += val;
    counter();
});
```